# chart.js не рендерится в Angular 1.5, es6

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, chart.js

Есть контроллер с данными

```
class FundraiserAboutController {
    constructor($stateParams, DataService) {
        this.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
        this.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
        this.data = [
            [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        ];
        this.onClick = function (points, evt) {
            console.log(points, evt);
        };
        this.datasetOverride = [{ yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' }, { yAxisID: 'y-axis-2' }];
        this.options = {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        id: 'y-axis-1',
                        type: 'linear',
                        display: true,
                        position: 'left'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'y-axis-2',
                        type: 'linear',
                        display: true,
                        position: 'right'
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
    }
}
const FundraiserAboutComponent = {
    controller  : FundraiserAboutController,
    template    : require('./fundraiser-about-template.html')
};
```

Это во View:

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="$ctrl.data"
        chart-labels="$ctrl.labels" chart-series="$ctrl.series" chart-options="$ctrl.options"
        chart-dataset-override="$ctrl.datasetOverride" chart-click="$ctrl.onClick">
</canvas>
```

Импорт:

```
import 'chart.js'; import 'angular-chart.js';

    angular
        .module('app', [
            'chart.js'
        ])
.component('fundraiserAboutComponent', FundraiserAboutComponent)
```

Comment: как контроллер в модуле объявлен? есть ли ошибки в консоли браузера?

Comment: ошибок вообще нет, появляется iframe, но канвас пустой, сейчас обновлю с указанием контроллера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не давно сталкивался с такой же проблемой, надеюсь смогу помочь.

В моем случае, графики не рисовались из-за некоторых опций, а именно из за `responsive` и `maintainAspectRatio`. Попробуйте задать им `true`, в моем случае это решило проблему.

В данный момент мой конфиг выглядит так:

```
var barChartOptions = {
    animation: false,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    elements: {
        rectangle: {
            borderWidth: 1
        }
    },
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'label'
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            },
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: не помогает может еще что-то?

Comment: поставил респонсив false и заработало

Comment: надо было завернуть канвас в родительский контейнер, спасибо что подтолкнули